# Unable to update text box on HTML Page using server side script

Tags: google-apps-script

Team,

I am unable to update a text box on a HTML page using server side script. There is a server side code and one HTML page - built using Googl App Script.

server.gs

```
function doGet(e)
{
var form =      HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html');   
form.listId = "categories";   form.datalist = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"];   
return form.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
}

function updatescreen(form)
{
try
{
      if (form.listId == "Category 1") 
      {
          form.myExpense = 2000;
          Logger.clear();
          Logger.log("2000");
          return; 
      }
      if (form.listId == "Category 2") 
      {
          form.myExpense = 3000;
          Logger.clear();
          Logger.log("3000");
          return; 
      }

      //form.myExpense = 4000;
      Logger.clear();
      Logger.log("4000");
      return;   
}   
catch (error)   
   {
      return error.toString();
   }
 }
```

form.html

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="myExpense" placeholder=1000>
      <input list="<?= listId ?>" name="<?= listId ?>"
          onclick = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(screenupdated)
              .updatescreen(this.parentNode);
              return true;>
          <datalist id="<?= listId ?>">
                <? for (var i=0; i<datalist.length; i++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= datalist[i] ?>">
                <? } ?>
          </datalist> 

      <input type="submit" name = "refresh" value="Update Screen" 
             onclick="this.value='Updating Screen ...';
                      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(screenupdated)
                      .updatescreen(this.parentNode);
                      return false;"> </form> <div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function screenupdated(status) 
    {
        document.getElementById('myForm').refresh.value = "Update Screen";
        document.getElementById('myForm').show();
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>  
      input { display:block; margin: 20px; } 
</style>
```

My questions are as follows:

1. While trying to add actions upon selection of the drop down list named as "listID" - the onclick function did not direct the control to script "updatescreen"; I was trying to update the text box "myExpense" with values based on the selection in the list box "listID". The text box "myExpense" is not getting updated
2. I tried to use a button to update the screen - still it did not work. When I tried to add a logger to see if the control is being passed on to the server side  observer a strange behaviour - when the line form.myExpense = 4000; is reached - it does not even update the log. when that line is commented - logger works.

Any ideas - how this can be approached?

Thank you for the help.

Hussain.

Answer (score 0):

Team,

I figured this out. The server side can not update the text boxes directly. It can only pass on the return value to the successhandler and successhandler then can update the field.

Revised codes are given below:

server.gs

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var form =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html');
  form.listId = "categories";
  form.datalist = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"];
  return form.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function updatescreen(form)
{
  try
  {
      var returnvalue = 0;

      if (form.listId == "Category 1")
      {
          returnvalue = 2000;
          Logger.clear();
          Logger.log("2000");
          return;
      }
      if (form.listId == "Category 2")
      {
          returnvalue = 3000;
          Logger.clear();
          Logger.log("3000");
          return;
      }

      return returnvalue;
  }
  catch (error)
  {
       return error.toString();
  }
}
```

form.html

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="myExpense" placeholder=1000>
      <input list="<?= listId ?>" name="<?= listId ?>"
          onclick = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(screenupdated)
              .updatescreen(this.parentNode);
              return true;>
          <datalist id="<?= listId ?>">
                <? for (var i=0; i<datalist.length; i++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= datalist[i] ?>">
                <? } ?>
          </datalist>

      <input type="submit" name = "refresh" value="Update Screen"
             onclick="this.value='Updating Screen ...';
                      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(screenupdated)
                      .updatescreen(this.parentNode);
                      return false;">




<script>
    function screenupdated(status)
    {
        document.getElementById('myForm').refresh.value = "Update Screen";
        document.getElementById('myForm').myExpense.value = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Thank you all.

Hussain.